# MFMessageComposeViewController bar transparent

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a MFMessageComposeViewController modally.

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller =[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = @"Welcome to my app!";
    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"99999999", nil];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:controller
                       animated:TRUE
                     completion:nil];
}
```

The navigation bar of the MFMessageComposeViewController appears transparent.

The controller is appearing like this:

[image: MFMessageComposeViewController]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: What changes have you made to the navigation bar using the appearance proxy?

Comment: Thank you! you've just hit the culprit! That was the problem. If you format this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made changes to the navigation bar using the appearance proxy. Either revert those changes, or override them directly on `MFMessageComposeViewController`'s navigation bar.